# Angular Stopping the execution of the program before the server response

Tags: angular, typescript

Problem: there is a nullable boolean property isAuthorized, a request is sent to the server in the service constructor to get information about the user and make sure he is authorized.

```
private _isAuthorized: boolean | null = null;
public get isAuthorized() {
    return this._isAuthorized;
}
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.update();
}
async update() {
     try {
         this.data = await this.getUserInfo();
         console.log(this.data.userName);
         this.userName = this.data.userName;
         this._isAuthorized = true;
     }
     catch (err) {
         ...
     }
}
getUserInfo(){
    ...
    return this.http.get<User>(this.url, { headers: header }).toPromise();
}
```

However, the isAuthorized property can be accessed while it is still null (that is, until the server has responded).

Comment: Well, in order to mitigate this, you should use an observable instead of a plain boolean. This way you can filter the invalid values like null.

Comment: Ok, but what exactly do you want to accomplish? You described current situation, but what is the problem? How do you want to use this `isAuthorized` property?

Comment: @AdrianKokot in guard's canActivate

Comment: Ok, so you can return observable from canActivate. That's perfect use case for this scenario. Can you show us your guard code?

Comment: @AdrianKokot I will try. Thanks